# No Angular syntax coloration in Intellij

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, colors

I recently imported an existing project into IntelliJ that uses Angular6+ and Typescript.
Unfortunately, I can't get the syntax coloration to work as expected (see image below), even though IntelliJ did recognize Typescript at some point and I downloaded the AngularJS plugin from [this adress](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs) and copied it in the Idea > plugins folder. I then followed [this Jet Brains Angular page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html) but I still don't see coloration in my code (you can however see what I expect on the capture "Generating code with Angular Schematics").

Has anyone ever experienced the same problem ?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide !

[edit] Here's the image of what I get :
[Syntax coloration no working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQYQ7.png)

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: please can you elaborate on this? what do you mean saying that it doesn't work as expected? Please provide screenshots illustrating this

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I had put an image, this is my first post on Stack Overflow, I'm not that familiar with the commands :/ I edited my question to provide an image.
No @yole I have the community version, do you think it does not support it ?

Comment: Can you check the settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) under `Editor > Code Style` if there is an entry for "Typescript"? Additionally, in the right bottom corner there is a little head. If you click on it, there is a bar you can move from "None" to "Inspection". Move it to "Inspection" and disable "Power Save Mode".

Comment: Hello @kedenk,
Thank you for considering this. I don't see Typescript in Editor > Code Style (among Java, HTML etc right?). Would you know how to add it ?
Also the bottom right corner head in indeed on "Inspection" and "Power Save Mode" is off.

Comment: What IntelliJ do you use? Is Typescript under `Editor > Languages & Frameworks` listed? You need also the NodeJS Plugin (`Editor > Plugins`search for NodeJS and install it).

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.6
I don't see Typescript in Editor > Languages & Frameworks, however my typescript file icons show the 'TS' label.
In Editor > Plugins, search 'NodeJS' returns 'No plugin found'. (I don't know if it's related, but running 'node -v' in console shows v9.11.1 and I do have a nodejs folder in Program Files).

Comment: Again sorry if my explanations are not relevant, this is all new to me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript language is only supported in the Ultimate Edition of IntelliJ. See here: [IntelliJ Version Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

In the Ultimate Version, you are able to install a Typescript Plugin. Also, the NodeJS Plugin is only supported in the Ultimate edition which you need for Angular development.

Comment: Your welcome! Can you mark this as the answer for your question?